# OpenPGP tag 18/19 description confusion

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp

Can someone please clear up a bit of MDC and data encryption for me? in rfc 4880, it says:

> The plaintext of the data to be
>   encrypted is passed through the SHA-1
>   hash function, and the result of the
>   hash is appended to the plaintext in a
>   Modification Detection Code packet.
>   The input to the hash function
>   includes the prefix data described
>   above; it includes all of the
>   plaintext, and then also includes two
>   octets of values 0xD3, 0x14. These
>   represent the encoding of a
>   Modification Detection Code packet tag
>   and length field of 20 octets.

at first, it seems like the mdc (without its header data) is just: `sha1([data]) -> hash_value`

then the second sentence up to the semicolon makes it seem like `sha1(OpenPGP_CFB_extra_data + [data]) -> hash_value`

the stuff after the semicolon makes it seem like I am supposed to do `sha1([data] + "\xd3\x14") -> hash_value`. (this doesnt make sense at all, but it seems to be what is written)

what is going on?

after getting the correct MDC, what is done with it? is it its own packet, or something like this (according to my understanding) done?:

```
tag18_header + encrypt(plaintext + "\xd3\x14" + 20 byte hash)
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-52) and parts of the [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/download/) source code ([g10/cipher.c](http://cvs.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/branches/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4/g10/cipher.c?revision=4215&view=markup&sortby=author&pathrev=4215) seems to be the place where this is handled), I interpret it is like this:

- `0xd3` is the MDC packet tag.
- `0x14` is the MDC packet length (20 bytes).

The MDC hash is computed like this:

```
MCD_hash = SHA-1(OpenPGP_CFB_extra_data + [plaintext] + "\xd3\x14")
```

Then this is appended to the plaintext message and encrypted:

```
encrypt(OpenPGP_CFB_extra_data + [plaintext] + "\xd3\x14" + MDC_hash)
```

When decrypted, this hash is verified by computing SHA-1 of everything but the last 20 bytes and comparing the result to the last 20 bytes, as RFC 4880 writes ([page 50](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-50)):

> During decryption, the plaintext data should be hashed with SHA-1, *including the prefix data as well as the **packet tag** and **length field*** of the Modification Detection Code packet. The body of the MDC packet, upon decryption, is compared with the result of the SHA-1 hash.